# PR to a fork not showing up

Tags: git, github

This seems rather basic PR from a [fork](https://github.com/paulywill/InnisfilTM.github.io) set as my origin of a [fork](https://github.com/InnisfilTM/InnisfilTM.github.io) set as my upstream, however Github is not showing the Base fork repo in the dropdown.

When I go to the forks link they're not listed:

[image]

Now I did rename my origin fork, but am I missing something?

Why are both names not populated?

Am I limited to PRs for but the original project and not between my forks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the issue, I had to add myself as a contributor.